# In pandas, how to plot with multiple index?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have double index in Panda's dataframe like the example below.

```
           c         d
a  b         
1  3   1.519970 -0.493662
2  4   0.600178  0.274230
3  5   0.132885 -0.023688
4  6   2.410179  1.450520
```

How do I plot column 'c' as y-axis and index 'b' as x-axis. With one index, it is easy to plot. But I have trouble with multi index plotting. Thank you for any help!!.

Comment: Did you try `df.reset_index().plot(x="b",y="c")`?

Comment: Or, `df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).c.plot()`

Comment: Yes. I tried it. I have a very big data set. I was wondering if there is any other way without using reset_index() everytime? Thank you ..

Comment: If your dataset is so big that calling `reset_index` is an issue, you will have much larger issues when actually plotting it; or in other words, do not plot any data that you cannot affort to reshape.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the suggestion. If there is no other way, I will stick with using reset_index(). Really appreciate the help. Thank you guys.

Comment: Is the problem that your dataset is huge in terms of number of columns? You can also do `df['c'].reset_index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
Two options have been provided (in the comments) involving `reset_index`. They are

```
df.reset_index().plot(x="b",y="c")
```

Or,

```
df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).c.plot()
```

Both of these should work as expected, but will become expensive for large dataframes.

---

**Option 2**
If you are worried about memory, here's an option that does not involve resetting the index:

```
plt.plot(df.index.get_level_values(1), df.c)
```

`reset_index` generates copies of the data. This is more efficient, because it doesn't have to.